# Osmdroid Bonuspack - MyLocationNewOverlay

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I currently have a couple of features that are causing a few problems that where originally working but after changing some things around are now producing errors. Using Android Studio which allowed me to look at previous versions of the code but to no avail.

Anyway I have a MyLocationNewOverlay declared globally like so:

```
MyLocationNewOverlay location_overlay;
```

Which gets initiated when the user navigates to the activity with the map:

```
map = (MapView) findViewByID(R.id.map);
map.setVisibility(MapView.VISIBLE);

<..some working code that sets the tile source and the center..>

location_overlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(getApplicationContext(), map);
location_overlay.enableMyLocation();
location_overlay.setDrawAccuracyEnabled(true);
map.getOverlays().add(location_overlay);
map.invalidate();
```

When it was working this code displayed a little human marker with the accuracy circle around it but now it doesn't even though it doesn't produce any errors. Iv'e tried the now decrepit `MyLocationOverlay` which didn't work either.

The second issue lies within an 'onClick' method on a button that supposed to focus the map on the users current location, this also used to work.

```
public void onBtnFocusOnMe(View view){
    GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint(location_overlay.getMyLocation());
    if(gp != null){
        mapController.animateTo(gp);
        mapController.zoomTo(16);
    }
}
```

Which produces a null pointer error on `GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint(location_overlay.getMyLocation());`

Answer (score 1):

How I normally overlay some items is like this, it is not directly your solution but you can maybe extract something useful from here:

```
public void showStartGoalMarkers(GeoPoint start, GeoPoint goal) {
    List<OverlayItem> mStartGoalItems = new ArrayList<>();
    OverlayItem startItem = new OverlayItem("", "", start);
    Drawable newMarker = mMapView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_start);
    startItem.setMarker(newMarker);

    mStartGoalItems.add(startItem);
    OverlayItem goalItem = new OverlayItem("", "", goal);
    Drawable newMarker2 = mMapView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_end);
    goalItem.setMarker(newMarker2);
    mStartGoalItems.add(goalItem);

    mMapView.getOverlays().add(new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(mStartGoalItems, new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(int index, OverlayItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongPress(int index, OverlayItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    }, mMapView.getResourceProxy()));

}
```

and in the end you invalidate the map view. Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** the code for marking the current location and which also updates the current position when a new location is passed:

```
 private void markMyLocation(Location location) {
    mOverlayItems.add(0, new OverlayItem("", "", new GeoPoint(location)));

    if (mMyLocationOverlay == null) {
        mMyLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(mOverlayItems, new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(int index, OverlayItem item) {
                IMapController mapController = mMapView.getController();
                mapController.setCenter(item.getPoint());
                mapController.setZoom(mMapView.getMaxZoomLevel());
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongPress(int index, OverlayItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        }, mMapView.getResourceProxy());

        mMapView.getOverlays().add(mMyLocationOverlay);
        mMapView.getController().setZoom(16);

    } else {
        IMapController mapController = mMapView.getController();
        mapController.setCenter(mOverlayItems.get(0).getPoint());
        mMapView.invalidate();
    }
}
```

The MyLocationOverlay class:

```
public class MyLocationOverlay extends ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> {

List<OverlayItem> mMyLocation;
int mResourceId;

public MyLocationOverlay(List<OverlayItem> pList,
                            OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem> pOnItemGestureListener,
                            ResourceProxy pResourceProxy) {
    super(pList, pOnItemGestureListener, pResourceProxy);
    this.mMyLocation = pList;
    this.mResourceId = R.drawable.my_location;
}

 @Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapview, boolean arg2) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapview, true);

    if (!mMyLocation.isEmpty()) {

        IGeoPoint geoPointLocation = mMyLocation.get(0).getPoint();
        Point out = new Point();
        mapview.getProjection().toPixels(geoPointLocation, out);

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mapview.getResources(),
                mResourceId);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm,
                out.x - bm.getWidth() / 2,  //shift the bitmap center
                out.y - bm.getHeight() / 2,  //shift the bitmap center
                null);
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return super.onSingleTapUp(event, mapView);
    return true;
}
```

Basically what I do is I overwrite the single item in the  ArrayList mOverlayItems when the method is called and invalidate the map.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it has helped but unfortunately like you said not the solution for this question. The way you used an Array List and the ItemizedIconOverlay, does that allow you to go back and select a specific overlay? Iv'e just been adding my overlays like in my questions so managing them is a pain.

Comment: Yes, it is easy to access a specific Overlay and update the location of the marker for example. For example, if I want to have a marker that shows the current location of the user I create an Overlay only for that single marker and so I can easily access it and change the GeoPoint when needed. If you are interested in that I can copy you the code for that too.

Comment: Please do, it might shed some more light on the problem too! Thanks.